# How to randomize an array of functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, math

Beginner here, so my problem is only the last `function` in the `let videos = []` array works. The other functions work as well but only when they're the last index in the array. So I've tried assigning the functions to variables and put them in the `let videos = []` array and all the videos played at the same time. I have these set up to hide the other videos when 1 video is playing.

Also, I'm trying to make sure each video only plays 1 time.

```
function playNextVideo() { 
    let videos = [showVideo1(), showVideo2(), showVideo3()]; 
    let randomVideo = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length); 
    videos.splice(randomVideo,1); 
}

document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended',playNextVideo(),false);
```

Comment: `randomVideo` is index, so you should use `return videos[randomVideo]` and does `showVideo1()` return function?

Comment: Yes, it used to make the video visible only when it was the last item in the array, but that part is solved now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than invoke all three functions and worry about hiding the videos you don't want, just store references to the functions and execute only one at a time:

```
function playNextVideo() { 
    let videos = [ showVideo1, showVideo2, showVideo3 ]; 
    let randomVideo = Math.floor( Math.random() * videos.length ); 

    videos.splice(randomVideo, 1)[0](); // Splice out the element at position randomVideo. You'll get back an array of 1 element, so extract the 0th element (a function) and call it
}
```

Comment: better answer than what I suggested earlier.

Comment: This works! 2 small problems though. The video doesn't auto-play to the next video and each video can only play 1 time. I got an answer to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101727/how-to-prevent-a-video-array-from-playing-the-same-video-twice but I'm not sure how to apply that to my new situation.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the video from the array before playing it, so videos only play once. As for auto-playing the next video, you'll have to add an event handler to the videos so that when they finish, they automatically call the `playNextVideo()` function. Since you provided no details of the implementation of the actual videos, you're on your own for that part.

Comment: I found a simple solution, all I had to do was remove the parenthesis on the function in the event listener. Works 100% now!